# BufRead autocmd error for "*.*" and E45

Tags: autocmd, help-system, error

I have vim version 7.4.1689. It was running quite smoothly. But recently I noticed a problem that I didn't have before. Whenever I run `:help <something>` in command mode the following error shows up (say I ran the command `help normal`):

```
"various.txt" [readonly] 674L, 26915C
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commnads for "*.*":
E45: 'readonly option is set (add ! to override)
```

See attached picture.

I am mentioning all my `BufRead` autocmds here:

```
augroup SomeAutocmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.* write
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.* source $MYVIMRC
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.* setlocal foldmethod=marker
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.* silent loadview
augroup end
```

I have recently updated my plugins, and I started noticing this problem right after updating my plugins. My plugins are listed below (I am sorry, I have lot of plugins):

```
Plugin 'LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box'
Plugin 'MahbubAlam231/dragvisuals'
Plugin 'MahbubAlam231/hybrid-line-numbers'
Plugin 'MahbubAlam231/searching-with-blinking'
Plugin 'MahbubAlam231/vim-system-copy'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-quicklink'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-sort-motion'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-titlecase'
Plugin 'danro/rename.vim'
Plugin 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plugin 'justinmk/vim-sneak'
Plugin 'kana/vim-textobj-datetime'
Plugin 'kana/vim-textobj-entire'
Plugin 'kana/vim-textobj-indent'
Plugin 'kana/vim-textobj-line'
Plugin 'kana/vim-textobj-user'
Plugin 'mattn/webapi-vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'tibabit/vim-templates'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-abolish'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/ReplaceWithRegister'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/ZoomWin'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/matchit.zip'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
```

[image: BufRead autocmd problem and E45]
I had changed `*.*` to `*` in `BufRead` autocmds, but the problem didn't go away. I have tried to find solution to this online, but couldn't find any that helped.

Would be glad if someone points out what's going on and gives a solution.

Comment: You're trying to write back the help files as soon as you're opening them: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.* write`

Comment: I see! I missed it. Anyway I only need `autocmd BufNewFile *.* write`. I deleted the `BufRead` part, and it worked. Here I was thinking that updating the plugins changed something! Thanks :-)

Comment: @lcd047 you should write a full answer explaining the problem and solution.

Comment: Why are you constantly reloading your `vimrc` via autocmd? And why do you set foldmarker via autocmd for every file? You could also add `set foldmethod=marker` in your vimrc, so you don't need to set it locally for every file.

Comment: @Ralf The autocmd would load my `vimrc` only once when I create a new file or read a file, isn't it? And you're right about the `foldmethod` thing, I'll change that.

Comment: @MahbubAlam `vimrc` is sourced when you start Vim, then it is sourced when the file is read. If you open another file, it is sourced again. If you call `vim file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` and then do two times `:bn` to go to `file3.txt`, the `vimrc` was sourced 4 times.

Comment: I see, I will change that.

Comment: @Ralf I have deleted the sourcing `vimrc` autocmd, I see that my mappings that are in `.vimrc` are not working with `help-system` files, e.g., I have `,q` mapped to `:q!<cr>`, now that's not working with `help-system` files, I have to do `:q!<cr>`. I think if there isn't any serious problem with this autocmd I'll keep it. Is there any serious problem with this autocmd?

Comment: If the mappings arent working, they may not be properly defined or loaded, or they may be unmapped. You should ask a new question about that (and be prepared to debug your mapping).